# TypeError: first argument must be callable, defaultdict

Tags: python, defaultdict

The error comes from `publishDB = defaultdict(defaultdict({}))` I want to make a database like `{subject1:{student_id:{assignemt1:marks, assignment2:marks,finals:marks}} , {student_id:{assignemt1:marks, assignment2:marks,finals:marks}}, subject2:{student_id:{assignemt1:marks, assignment2:marks,finals:marks}} , {student_id:{assignemt1:marks, assignment2:marks,finals:marks}}}`. I was trying to populate it as `DB[math][10001] = a dict` and later read out as `d = DB[math][10001]`. Since, I am on my office computer I can not try different module.

Am I on right track to do so?

Comment: try `dict` instead of `{}` maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Such a nested `dict` structure can be achieved using a recursive `defaultdict` "tree":

```
def tree(): 
    return defaultdict(tree)

publishDB = tree()
```

At each level, the defaultdicts are instantiated with `tree` which is a zero-argument callable, as required.
Then you can simply assign marks:

```
publishDB[subject][student][assignment] = mark
```

Answer (score 2):

`defaultdict()` requires that its first argument be callable: it must be a class that you want an instance of, or a function that returns an instance.

`defaultdict({})` has an empty dictionary, which is not callable.

You likely want `defaultdict(dict)`, as `dict` is a class that returns a dictionary when instantiated (called).

But that still doesn't solve the problem... just moves it to a different level. The outer `defaultdict(...)` in `defaultdict(defaultdict(dict))` has the exact same issue because `defaultdict(dict)` isn't callable.

You can use a `lambda` expression to solve this, creating a one-line function that, when called, creates a `defaultdict(dict)`:

```
 defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
```

You could also use the lambda at the lower level if you wanted:

```
defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: {}))
```

Comment: this is part of the problem, but it isn't all of it. this doesn't work either: `publishDB = defaultdict(defaultdict(dict))` because `defaultdict(dict)` is being passed as the first argument for the outer dict, and it's not callable either.