# Initializing a dictionary of dictionaries for integer values with defaultdict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to initialize a dictionary of dictionary whose initial values are all 0 as follows:

```
all_votes = defaultdict(defaultdict(int))
```

So, I want `all_votes[i][j] = 0` for arbitrary indexes `i,j`.
However, I get a `TypeError: first argument must be callable` error. What's the proper way of doing what I want ?

Using `all_votes = defaultdict(dict)` works but it doesn't initialize all values to 0.

Comment: Top tip: Google your error messages.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How is this a duplicate? It doesn't provide an answer to my question. Same error could be produced from many different ways.

Comment: This: defaultdict(dict) is not a solution to my question

Comment: You have to change it slightly to your specific case, but the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40712881/3001761) shows how to use `lambda` to nest `defaultdict`s.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you. I think all_votes = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: 0)) did the trick.

Comment: Or `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))`.